# iOS Safari displaying "nan" for JSONObject double value

Tags: ios, json, mobile-safari

My Android app retrieves a small JSONObject via a HTTP call. It contains a decimal number that I fetch with `.getDouble( "TempF" )`. This usually works but occasionally fails. In trying to determine what's going on, I've fetched the same item using Safari on iOS. Sometimes instead of the numeric value, it displays `nan`.

The JSON normally looks like this: `{"TempF":63.5}`. I'm adding code to catch any `JSONException` to log the received value.

I don't know where this is coming from. According to Google documentation, `.getDouble()` either returns a valid `double` or throws a `JSONException`. And apparently `nan` is not part of the JSON spec. What's going on here?

Comment: We can't help you without an example of the JSON that causes the problem. (Just the [**minimal** example demonstrating the problem](/help/mcve), of course.)

Comment: Evidently this "nan" is being returned by the peripheral's Arduino library that reads the temperature from the thermocouple. This seems nonstandard: shouldn't it return `null` if there's no value available? JSON doesn't define a "nan" as far as I can tell.

Comment: You're right that there's no `NaN` in JSON. Whether it should be output as `null` or omitted entirely is a style choice. :-) (Using `null` where a double is expected is a problem for some environments.)

Comment: I discovered the `.isnan()` function that apparently can tell me if the value is NAN and handle as desired.